# css - add and position a div without disturbing the rest of the document

Tags: css

I have to add a weather widget to a website whose markup is a total mess (it was converted from a wordpress site using a website copier).  I can't add it to the current structure because it throws everything off, so I wanted to drop it in at the top of the document and use absolute positioning to deal with it.  This works to an extent, but it falls short with different resolutions, browsers, etc.  If I try relative positioning it pushes the rest of the document down.  Any hints on what to research to solve this problem short of reading the css spec?

Update:

I was able to figure out a solution by combining the information that all of you provided along with "%".  I used absolute positioning and set position:absolute;right:28%.

Thank you all for taking the time to answer so quickly.

Comment: What is the problems with absolute positioning? Without any further information, it seems it is the natural solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with Joseph and Kasturi.

**You want `position:absolute`**

```
div#weather-widget{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:100px;
  width:150px;
}
```

*Maybe setting `height`, `width`, `font-size`, `line-height`, etc. would help solve your browser inconsistency problems.  Also, look into a CSS reset template.*

Beyond that, you would really need to post some code for more definitive help.

Reference:

- [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 1):

This definitely needs a positioning attribute and I would suggest `fixed`.  The only other option of taking it "out of flow" is to float it, but that could get messy.

so without further ado:

```
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:0px; /* or whatever */
}
```

And that's what I'd do anyhow :P

Comment: `absolute` takes it out of flow too, and `fixed` keeps it at the same spot on the screen even as you scroll, which might not be the desired effect.

Comment: @JohnB true.  I made an assumption based on the nature of the project.  If the PO does need to use absolute positioning, it probably needs to be a direct child element of body, though.

Answer (score 0):

`Position: fixed` is what you are looking for... it doesnt disturb the rest of the document.... and you might need `z-index` to pop it on the front ....

Comment: How do I deal with different resolutions and how they affect its placement?  Thanks to both of you for taking the time to answer.